# Erfahrung haben: mit oder im?

Tags: preposition

Sagt man

> Ich habe Erfahrung im …

oder

> Ich habe Erfahrung mit …

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich habe Erfahrung im Photovoltaik-Zellen.

Wenn nicht, welche Präposition/Konstruktion kann man verwenden?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual construction is `Erfahrung mit ...` for nouns and `Erfahrung im ...` for verbs (where you'd use the progressive form in English); there are, obviously, exceptions. A few examples:

> Ich habe Erfahrung **mit** Photovoltaik-Zellen / unfähigen Vorgesetzten / Textverarbeitungssoftware.
>
> Ich habe Erfahrung **im** Aufbereiten von Informationen / Umgang mit Juristen / Lösen komplexer Probleme.
>
> Ich habe Erfahrung **in** der Immobilienbranche.

Comment: Note that "Erfahrung *mit* der Immobilienbranche" works as well. `in` implies you've been an estate agent, `mit` means you've been a customer.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't agree with this answer. The pronoun ("mit", "in" or also "als") indicates different meanings. It has nothing to do with the lexical category of the following expression.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to give a few examples.

Comment: *im* is usually used for verbs turned into nouns, as it is as short for *in dem*. You can say both "Durch meine Arbeit habe ich Erfahrung in *dem Aufbereiten* (or im Aufbereiten) ..." oder "Ich habe Erfahrungen mit *dem Aufbereiten* ... sammeln können* for example.

Comment: Both Erfahrung mit and Erfahrung in are used exclusively with nouns. ("im" = "in dem").